# Having trouble understanding Re-derivation of Young’s Equation

Tags: thermodynamics, geometry, surface-tension

I was going over a section 2.1 of [this article (regarding Young's Equation](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/49063) and for some reason I wasn't able to derive E10 from E9 (see image below). I know it is more about the trigonometry of the problem, but when I tried to derive it myself it became cumbersome real fast and I don't get to E10. I would appreciate if someone could help me with that.

[image]

Comment: write $c=cos(\theta)$ and $sin^2(\theta)=1-c^2$, then divide the terms in the large parentheses you do get $c=cos(t)$ as promised

Answer (score 1):

The first parenthesis in E9 is simplified into

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sin^2\theta + \cos\theta \frac{-(1 - \cos\theta)(2 + \cos\theta)}{1 + \cos\theta} \\
= &(1 - \cos^2\theta) - \cos\theta \frac{2 - \cos\theta - \cos^2\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} \\
= &1 - \cos\theta \frac{\cos\theta(1 + \cos\theta) + (2 - \cos\theta - \cos^2\theta)}{1 + \cos\theta} \\
= &1 - \cos\theta \frac{2}{1 + \cos\theta} \\
= &\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}
\end{aligned}
$$

The second parenthesis in E9 is simplified into

$$
\begin{aligned}
&2(1 - \cos\theta) - \frac{(1 - \cos\theta)(2 + \cos\theta)}{1 + \cos\theta} \\
= &\frac{2 (1-\cos\theta)(1+\cos\theta) - (1-\cos\theta)(2+\cos\theta)}{1+\cos\theta} \\
= &\frac{2 - 2\cos^2\theta - 2 + \cos\theta + \cos^2\theta}{1+\cos\theta} \\
= &\frac{-\cos^2\theta + \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} \\
= &\cos\theta \frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now use these simplifications in the E9

$$(\gamma_{sl} - \gamma_{so}) \frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} + \gamma \cos\theta \frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} = 0$$

$$\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} \Bigl( (\gamma_{sl} - \gamma_{so}) + \gamma \cos\theta \Bigr) = 0$$

I do not know specifics about the above equation, but from purely mathematical point of view it has a singularity at $\theta = \pi$, and for $\theta = 0$ you cannot assume the term in parenthesis to be equal to zero.

If we neglect these two special cases for $\theta$ the Eq. E9 is simplified into

$$\boxed{\gamma_{sl} + \gamma \cos\theta = \gamma_{so}} \tag {E10}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble in simplifying the trigonometric equations, you can use the symbolic calculator in MATLAB/python. Using the symbolic code in MATLAB (shown below), you get

```
G = (1 - cos(theta))*(2 + cos(theta))/(1 + cos(theta))
F = (gamma_sl - gamma_so)*(sin(theta)^2 - cos(theta)*G) + gammma*(2*(1 - cos(theta)) - G)
simplify(F)
```

which yields the output

```
-((cos(theta) - 1)*(gamma_sl - gamma_so + gammma*cos(theta)))/(cos(theta) + 1)
```

As pointed out in another answer, this eventually yields E10 as `cos(theta) = 1` is satisfied only at `theta = 0`.